# System zoom with screen capture

Tags: macos, osx-lion, screenshot, osx-mountain-lion, quartz-graphics

We are developing screen capture utility which allows users to capture selected area on screen. Which works on 10.7 and above.
As per apple Technical Q&A QA1741 we have used below API to capture screen.

`CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(displayId,selectedArea)`

This API works fine for normal scenario. Howerver there is one issue with systen screen zoom feature(cmd+shift+=)

Whenever we try to capture zoomed area, we are not getting correct output.

I know that we need to apply screen zoom factor to selected rect. But I am not finding any API to get screen zoom level.
Can any one show me some pointers to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hello, I am developing the same utility app. Could u help me out?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Sorry. I didnt find any solution for this issue